# Github Action for SQL Database

Tags: sql, github, yaml, github-actions

I am using the Github action to automate my Azure SQL database changes and tried my 'yaml' code like the following but it gives framework error as given below.

Github Yaml code,

```
name: SQL-Action
on:
  push:
    branches:
     - SQL 
pull_request:
types: [opened, synchronize, reopened]
branches:
  - dev
env:
 AZURE_FUNCTIONAPP_PACKAGE_PATH: Project/publish
 CONFIGURATION: Release
 DOTNET_CORE_VERSION: 6.0.x
 DOTNETFRAMEWORK_VERSION: 4.8
 WORKING_DIRECTORY: Project
 SQL_WORKING_DIRECTORY: Project.Database
 TEST_DIRECTORY: Project.Test

jobs:
 build:
  name: Build
   runs-on: self-hosted-win

steps:
- uses: actions/checkout@v2
- name: Setup .NET Core
  uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v1
  with:
    dotnet-version: ${{ env.DOTNET_CORE_VERSION }}
- name: Clean
  run: dotnet clean "${{ env.SQL_WORKING_DIRECTORY }}/Project.Database.sqlproj" --configuration ${{ env.CONFIGURATION }}    
- name: Build SQL Database project
  run: dotnet build "${{ env.SQL_WORKING_DIRECTORY }}/Project.Database.sqlproj" --configuration ${{ env.CONFIGURATION }} /p:VisualStudioVersion=17.3.2
 
- name: Restore
  run: dotnet restore "${{ env.WORKING_DIRECTORY }}"
- name: Publish SQL Database changes
  uses: azure/sql-action@v1
  with:
    server-name: xxxx.database.windows.net
    connection-string: ${{ secrets.AZURE_SQL_CONNECTION_STRING }}
    dacpac-package: "${{ env.WORKING_DIRECTORY }}/Project.Database/bin/${{ env.CONFIGURATION }}/Project.Database.dacpac"
```

The error in the build task,

```
   MSBuild version 17.3.2+561848881 for .NET
  Determining projects to restore...
  Nothing to do. None of the projects specified contain packages to restore.
 
 
 C:\Users\ContainerAdministrator\AppData\Local\Microsoft\dotnet\sdk\6.0.408\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1220,5): error MSB3644: The reference assemblies for .NETFramework,Version=v4.8 were not found. To resolve this, install the Developer Pack (SDK/Targeting Pack) for this framework version or retarget your application. You can download .NET Framework Developer Packs at https://aka.ms/msbuild/developerpacks
    0 Warning(s)
    1 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:00:04.72
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

Comment: I observe you're using a self hosted runner, and it could be that some packages are missing there. [This issue](https://github.com/actions/runner-images/issues/5055) was related to a similar problem, but seems to have been resolved on github runners. It might however give some insights about what has been done at the time to resolve the problem.

Comment: The workflow in your question in not valid. Most probably, a copy/paste issue. Please edit your question and reformat it. You may use https://rhysd.github.io/actionlint/ for this.